# Testing to see if a drive is mounted in linux

Tags: linux, shell, mount

I have seen multiple questions on this but none that specifically related to mine. I am creating a shell script and i want to test certain drives to see if they are already mounted. I am looking to test if `cdrive` is mounted. The code i have used to mount this is `mount /dev/sda1 media/cdrive` I am looking to create a piece of code that will echo out to the terminal if the drive has already mounted. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If wanna check both that `/dev/sda1` is mounted on `/media/cdrive`:

```
grep -q '^/dev/sda1 /media/cdrive ' /proc/mounts && echo "mounted" || echo "not mounted"
```

If wanna check if something is mounted on `/media/cdrive`:

```
grep -q ' /media/cdrive ' /proc/mounts && echo "mounted" || echo "not mounted"
```